# SpriteKit particles – how to set filteringMode to nearest

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

With standard SKSpriteNodes, I am using nearest as the filteringMode:

```swift
snowman.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest;
```

I want to use this for my particle effects too. `SKTextureFilteringMode.nearest;` doesn't work for particleTextures (have tried), but managed to find `particleTexture?.filteringMode`, but can't find any info on how to set this to nearest. The following DOES NOT work:

```swift
node.particleTexture?.filteringMode = .nearest
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure spritekit can do this natively. however you can "trick" it by laundering your texture through a shader. it's a bit more convoluted but it works. left side is a particle emitter with a "hard edge" shader. the right side is a normal emitter. [image]

```
import SpriteKit

class PixelArtEmitter: SKNode {
    var emitter:SKEmitterNode?
    
    private var shader_source:String = """
#define RESOLUTION 50.0 //width and height dimension of pixel art; pass as a uniform if you want to make this dynamic

void main() {
    vec2 st = v_tex_coord.xy;

    //quantize the xy values for "hard edge" effect
    float x = floor(st.x * RESOLUTION) / RESOLUTION;
    float y = floor(st.y * RESOLUTION) / RESOLUTION;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(x, y));
}
"""
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        //create an sks file in xcode using your pixel art image as texture
        emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "PixelArtEmitter.sks")
        emitter?.targetNode = self

        //add shader
        emitter?.shader = SKShader(source: shader_source)

        self.addChild(emitter ?? SKNode())
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```